# Como tomar el ultimo elemento de una lista en java?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, loops

Tengo la siguiente lista

```
listNivelesPersona2 = nivelesPersonaService.findNivelesPersonaConsultaHorario(cvePersona);
```

quiero recuperar el ultimo registro de  la hora de entrada y de salida, hago lo siguiente

```
    for (NivelesPersona nivelesPersona : listNivelesPersona2) {
        System.out.println("HORARIO" + nivelesPersona.getHorarios().getHorarioEntrada() + " " +nivelesPersona.getHorarios().getHorarioSalida());
    }
```

y me muestra todos los horarios de entrada y de salida que tiene esa persona

```html
HORARIO11:30 18:00
HORARIO12:00 19:00
HORARIO15:00 20:00
```

yo quiero tomar siempre el ultimo registro, que es el mas nuevo, en este caso solo me interesa el de 15:00 a 20:00, para mostrarlo en vista, como puedo obtener ese ultimo registro?

Comment: Tal vez te sirve esta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/687842/3239070

Answer (score 2):

Para que saques el ultimo registro de una lista solo tendrías que saber cuantos elementos vienen en la lista, después saca el ultimo elemento de la lista, ejemplo,

```
NivelesPersona nivelesPersona = listNivelesPersona2.get(listNivelesPersona2.size() -1 );
```

la función get me trae el valor en la posición que le indiquemos, y la función size me devuelve la suma total de los elementos en la lista, entonces si la lista tiene 10 registros cuando con la función size me imprime 10 y con la funcion get le digo que me traiga el valor que esta en la posición 10 que seria el ultimo de la lista. 
hay ya estas obteniendo el ultimo registro de la lista.

Comment: Cuidado con los indices. Si la lista tiene 10 elementos es cierto que 'size' retorna 10, pero internamente no existe un elemento en la posición 10, ya que el índice comienza en 0 y termina en 9 (o sea, 10 elemento, como retorna 'size').

Comment: Ese código no compila (debería ser `size()` , ya que es es un método) y además fallaría porque debería ser `.size()-1`

Comment: Los comentarios son validos, y ya se edito la respuesta, pero la votación negativa sobra por que la respuesta que plantee soluciona el problema publicado..